# How do you write, "People for others" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Can you tell me how to write/say, "People for Others" in Latin?

Comment: I'm not sure what your sentence is intended to mean. Can you edit your question to explain what exactly the phrase means, as well as a little bit of its context. Are you looking for a motto? A grammatical relationship? What kind of people? Like "the Roman people" or "people in general" or "persons"? The more information you give us, the more accurate the answers will be!

Answer (score 1):

According to Wiktionary and Etymonline, the word "people" derives from the Latin word populus. So it seems fitting to use the word populus.

One translation would be:

```
Populus pro aliis. (People for others.)
```

The word "populus" is a collective noun that means people. The word "aliis" is the ablative plural form of the adjective "alius, alia, alium".

The adjective "aliis" is used substantively in this context to mean "other people".